# Javascript .format() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, date

I have array of dates in sql format. So dates[0]="2001-01-01", I need to format it in format: "1-Jan-12". As I found it [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) it should work like this.

```
tmpDate=Date.parse(dates[0]);
var date=tmpDate.format("dd-mm-yy");
```

it says: Uncaught TypeError: Object 978307200000 has no method 'format' 
So type of my object is string however it should be date.

```
console.log($.type(tmpDate));
```

Also says "number". Why?

Comment: The link you posted is suggesting to use a Date Format library. Have you included this library in your project? This functionality is not built into native JS.

Comment: i think same question asking here yesterday ?

Comment: Yep, the same question.

Comment: Yep, my mistake. But Ben found better sollution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is simpler to use plain javascript without plugins or 3rd party libraries.  If that is what you are going for, there is some great documentation of the `Date` object and methods at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp.

Here is the simplest way to do this in javascript from http://jsfiddle.net/bbankes/pVU24/

```
var monthAbbreviations = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

var dates = ['2001-01-01'];
var tmpDate = new Date(dates[0]);

var day = tmpDate.getUTCDate();
var mo = monthAbbreviations[tmpDate.getUTCMonth()];
var yr = String(tmpDate.getUTCFullYear()).substring(2,4);

var formattedDate = day + '-' + mo + '-' + yr;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp), `Date.parse()` returns the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970. Thus you are getting back a number.

I think you are looking for this:
`tmpDate = new Date (dates [0]);`